# How to avoid character limit when uploading document via VB app?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, splistitem

We have an in-house application that, among other things, generates an Excel spreadsheet and then uploads it to a document library on a SharePoint 2013 site. I sent the developer the UNC path to the library so that he could just upload the file using WEBDAV, but in several cases he's seeing an error that the path is invalid. As near as I can tell, we're probably running into the 128-character limit for path components.

According to [this TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff919562(v=office.14).aspx) for SP2010, there is no limit for encoded URLs. I couldn't find an equivalent article for SP2013, but I assume it hasn't changed. I'd rather not have the developer blindly trying stuff, so I was hoping to find a better solution first.

**If we encode the UNC path to the library, will it still be accepted as a valid WebDAV path? If not, what is a better way to upload the file in VB?**

Comment: Encoding it is not going to make a difference I don't think, you'll still be hitting a character limit. Try to eliminate spaces if you can, could you use a drop off library and let the content organizer route it to the proper place?

Comment: check this one https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2933738?wa=wsignin1.0